# Wondering how to architect this database of users and server ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm using rails 3.1rc4, and was wondering what would be "the rails way" to architect this information into a database.  Currently I have a users table that was generated with devise.  Each user has only one corresponding server that is given an id that would look something like this '200123989' by rackspace cloud servers.  I want to store this server id along with the time it was created in a database.  Would the server information such as the id and the date created go in a separate table from the users table (The user can only have one server)?

I was thinking something like a 'has_one' and 'belongs_to' relationship if I created a relationships table.

In short, would you stick this all in the users table or create a relationship table, a server table, and a users table.  What are the best practices in this situation?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way to go (not just the Ruby way I suppose), would be to have one table for the servers and one for the users. Since the "user-has-a-server"-relation is a one-to-many and not many-to-many relation, a field in the users table would suffice:

```
,-----------.       .-----------.       .----------.
|  Users    |       |  Servers  |       |  Clouds  |
|-----------|       |-----------|       |----------|
| id        |     ,>| id        |     ,>| id       |
| server_id |-----' | cloud_id  |-----' | ...      |
| ...       |       | created   |       '----------'
`-----------'       | ...       |
                    '-----------'
```

Putting the server information inside the Users table would be to violate the second normal form. I.e., only information *unique* to a user should go into that table. Another way to put it would be that any information that can't be identified by the Users.id alone (and a server can't) should go into it's own table. I think that [this page explains relational database normalization](http://en.csharp-online.net/Relational_Databases_101%E2%80%94Understanding_Relational_Database_Normalization) in a very good way.

Comment: Is there a way to override the server id to be the rackspace id? Or would it be better to create another column in the server table like cloud_id?

Comment: Sounds like you should have a 'Clouds' table as well, if many servers go into the same cloud.

Comment: Even so, there would be no need for a "relationship table".